# Why won't my cell width stay fixed on this table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

Very new to HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Threw the three files into a single HTML file, code below.

I am creating a simple grid for a Checkers game. If hard coded in HTML with the same styles this works, but when using Javascript to generate the HTML the width keeps resizing with the window. I am trying to set each cell at 60x60 pixels, but only the height is being enforced when the window is resized smaller than the overall grid size.

What am I missing here? I entered a width for the dive that holds the grid equal to the number of cells * 60. It looks correct if the window size is bigger than this, but if resized horizontally smaller, it collapses the cells.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Checkers Grid</title>
<style>
table   { table-layout: fixed;
          empty-cells: show;
          background-color: #336666;
        }

div#Player { position: absolute;
             top: 100;
             left: 150px;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;           
             border: none;
           }

table#PlayerGrid { background-color: 336666;
                   color: red;
                 }

td  {}

td.squareOne { background-color: yellow;
              height: 60px;
              width: 60px;          
         }

td.squareTwo { background-color: grey; 
             }

body    { background-color: black;
          font-family: Arial,Times,serif;
          font-size: 12pt;
        }

a   { target: new front;
    }
</style>
<script>
// Generate game grid based on customer input
function addTable(row, col){    
    var grid = document.getElementById("Main");
    // Create HTML table
    var table_size = col * 60;
    var html = "";
    html += "<div id=\"Player\" name=\"Player\" width = \"" + table_size + "\">";
    html += "<table id=\"PlayerGrid\">";
    // Add Cells to table
    for(var i=1; i<=col; ++i)
    {
        //Create a <tr>
        html += "<tr>";
        for(var j=1; j<=row; ++j)
        {
            // Create <td> in each row          
            //even-even
            if(i%2==0 && j&2===0)
            {
                html+= "<td class = \"squareOne\">";
                html+= "</td>";
            } else 
            //even-odd
            if(i%2==0 && j%2>0)
            {
                html+= "<td class = \"squareTwo\">";
                html+= "</td>";
            } else
            //odd-even
            if(i%2>0 && j%2===0)
            {
                html+= "<td class = \"squareTwo\" h>";
                html+= "</td>";
            } 
            //odd-odd
            else
            {
                html+= "<td class = \"squareOne\">";
                html+= "</td>";
            }           
        } //end columns
        html += "</tr>";
    } // end rows
    html += "</table>";
    html += "</div>"; // End Player div
    grid.innerHTML = html;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="addTable(8,8)">
<div id="Main">Replace this text with game grid.</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign min-width property for the table cell like below.

```
td.squareOne { background-color: yellow;
          height: 60px;
          min-width: 60px;          
     }
```

Comment: obviously it should work. Where i can see the issue? Can you give the site url?

Comment: This does work, thanks. Couldn't find any reason that caused it not to work, but copied from previous version with this adjustment and it is working properly this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the table width to 480px:

```
table   { table-layout: fixed;
          empty-cells: show;
          background-color: #336666;
          width: 480px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//your test this code

 table {
   background-color: #336666;
   empty-cells: show;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
   table-layout: fixed;
  }
  div#Player {
   border: 10px solid #808080;
   margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
  table#PlayerGrid {
    color: #FF0000;
  }
  td.squareOne {
       background-color: #FFFF00;
       max-width: 100%;
       width: auto;
       padding:30px;
   }
  td.squareTwo {
    background-color: #808080;
  }
  body {
    font-family: Arial,Times,serif;
     font-size: 12pt;
   }
   @media  screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:480px){
   td.squareOne,
    td.squareTwo{
    padding:20px;
  }
 }
  @media screen and (min-width:600px) and (max-width:800px){
  td.squareOne,
  td.squareTwo{
    padding:25px;
 }
   } 
    @media screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width:1024px){
    td.squareOne,
    td.squareTwo{
    padding:40px;
 }
  }
```